# NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException occuring with no autolayout

Tags: ios, exception, ios6, interface-builder, xcode4.5

When testing on device running iOS 5.1 there is an `NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException`. I have searched on the issue and made sure that autoLayout is not checked for any of the nib files but the error is still there. Any ideas? Using xCode 4.5. This doesn't happen on a device running iOS 6 though.

Log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x325dc88f 0x34632259 0x325dc789 0x325dc7ab 0x322ea54d 0x322ea6bb 0x322ea423 0x3227b001 0x3227c861 0xce38b 0xa4009 0xa2f3b 0x32045b95 0x3209f8af 0x32048913 0x32048503 0x3203caff 0x2e2a2a7 0x3203c7d5 0x139929 0x1513d3 0x325363fd 0x3201ee07 0x3201edc3 0x3201eda1 0x3201eb11 0x3201e73d 0x32011b87 0x325b0b1b 0x325aed57 0x325af0b1 0x325324a5 0x3253236d 0x31689439 0x32031cd5 0x92e89 0x92e60)
```

Does the fact that `Document Versioning` Deployment is set to iOS 6.0 causes this issue?